# Simple recursive descent parser

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a simple recursive descent parser in Python that accepts the grammar ::= abc.
I'm using an array to store the input given by the user and validate that it's a correct one.

The code that I have:

```
i = 0    # Global variables
t = ''
entry= ''   

def nextToken():
    global i
    i += 1
    return entry[i]

def A():
    global t
    if t == 'a':     # Validation for the sequence abc that has to come in the input
        t = nextToken()
        if t == 'b':
            t = nextToken()
            if t == 'c':
                t = nextToken()
            else:
                print("expected c")
        else:
            print("expected b")
    else:
        print("expected a")


print("Input to validate: ")
entry= input()
t = entry[i]
A()
if t == '':
    print("Correct input ...")
else:
    print("Input error...")
```

When running the code and typing abc which should be a valid entry for the code, it shows

> error: string index out of range

I'm thinking that the issue is on the entry array, but not sure how to solve it. I'm new in this and will appreciate all help.

Comment: Is `entry` supposed to be a list or string? You start with making it a list of 100 strings, but then `entry = input()` replaces it with a string.

Comment: it's supposed to be a string too, i change the variable to entry = ' '

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Comment: The way you're handling nextToken is named and written like C. Python has a builtin https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next Using that would have solved the error when you get to the end. Also, you don't need any globals -- it would be easier to just pass "entry" to the function.

Answer (score 1):

After you've checked each of the three letters in the `entry`, you call `nextToken()` an extra time. This tries to index off the end of the string, which is what's causing your exception.

It looks to me like your code expects C-style null-terminated strings. In C, a pointer just off the end of a string (at the null byte) is equivalent to an empty string.

Here's what your various string variables would look like in C (at the end of the code, where you test `t == ''`):

```
| a | b | c | \0 |      | \0 |
  ^            ^           ^
  |            |           |
  entry        t           ''
```

But that's now how strings are represented in Python. Indexing off the end of the string causes an exception.

There are a few different ways you could resolve the issue. One idea would be to use `try` and `except` to catch the exception that gets raised in `nextToken()` and do something appropriate (e.g. setting `t` to an empty string).

But another idea would be to use slicing rather than simple indexing in `nextToken()`. A slice off the end of a string will be empty, rather than raising an exception. Try this:

```
def nextToken():
    global i
    i += 1
    return entry[i:i+1]  # change is here
```

Comment: Yes, I was given a similar example in c++ with a different grammar, the structure was similar and needed to adapt it so i can use my own grammars.

The code now works correctly and I can use that validation for some more instructions.

 Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Make sure you do check the end, lest you incorrectly accept "abcd"